# BigQuery API Listed Twice in APIs & Services Dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-bigquery

does anyone happen to know why the BigQuery API would be listed twice in the **APIs & Services Dashboard** in Google Clout Platform?

BigQuery seems to be functioning properly I just thought it was strange this is the only API that seems to be listed twice.. I don't think it could be enabled twice as both the links lead to the same overview page and all the metrics are the same.

[Duplicate Bigquery API listed in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXiFZ.png)

Comment: I have the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is apparently caused by the fact that **bigquery-json.googleapis.com** is an alias for **bigquery.googleapis.com**.

The BigQuery engineering team is aware of this issue and are working on resolving it.  All further updates should occur on this [Public report](https://issuetracker.google.com/164055589).